# Indexing mongoDb date(in unix timestamp) to solr 'date' (YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ) in mongo-connector(solr_doc_manager.py)

Tags: python, mongodb, solr

Is it possible to convert this time(unix timestamp from mongodb field) to sorl field(in format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ) during indexing phase  by tinkering solr_doc_manager.py or some other way in mongo-connector?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found it. I modified '_clean_doc' function in solr_doc_manager.py like this:

```
def _clean_doc(self, doc, namespace, timestamp):
    """Reformats the given document before insertion into Solr.

    This method reformats the document in the following ways:
      - removes extraneous fields that aren't defined in schema.xml
      - unwinds arrays in order to find and later flatten sub-documents
      - flattens the document so that there are no sub-documents, and every
        value is associated with its dot-separated path of keys
      - inserts namespace and timestamp metadata into the document in order
        to handle rollbacks

    An example:
      {"a": 2,
       "b": {
         "c": {
           "d": 5
         }
       },
       "e": [6, 7, 8]
      }

    becomes:
      {"a": 2, "b.c.d": 5, "e.0": 6, "e.1": 7, "e.2": 8}

    """

    # Translate the _id field to whatever unique key we're using.
    # _id may not exist in the doc, if we retrieved it from Solr
    # as part of update.

    """mf mongo-connector extension"""
    if 'created' in doc:
        if isinstance( doc['created'], int ):
            utc_dt = datetime(1970, 1, 1) + timedelta(seconds=doc['created'])
            doc['created'] = utc_dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
    if 'updated' in doc:
        if isinstance( doc['updated'], int ):
            utc_dt = datetime(1970, 1, 1) + timedelta(seconds=doc['updated'])
            doc['updated'] = utc_dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
    """end mf mongo-connector extension"""

    if '_id' in doc:
        doc[self.unique_key] = u(doc.pop("_id"))

    # Update namespace and timestamp metadata
    if 'ns' in doc or '_ts' in doc:
        raise errors.OperationFailed(
            'Need to set "ns" and "_ts" fields, but these fields already '
            'exist in the document %r!' % doc)
    doc['ns'] = namespace
    doc['_ts'] = timestamp

    # SOLR cannot index fields within sub-documents, so flatten documents
    # with the dot-separated path to each value as the respective key
    flat_doc = self._formatter.format_document(doc)

    # Only include fields that are explicitly provided in the
    # schema or match one of the dynamic field patterns, if
    # we were able to retrieve the schema
    if len(self.field_list) + len(self._dynamic_field_regexes) > 0:
        def include_field(field):
            return field in self.field_list or any(
                regex.match(field) for regex in self._dynamic_field_regexes
            )
        return dict((k, v) for k, v in flat_doc.items() if include_field(k))
    return flat_doc
```

This converted time date during indexing.